# Rename *.pdf into convert.pdf

Tags: python

How do I change the name of some PDF file (*.pdf) to convert.pdf?

There is only one PDF file in the relevant directory.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Python instead of just doing the trivial answer in bash/cmd/whatever your shell is?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You should post what you have so far, so we can help out rather than write the code for you :]

Answer (score 3):

It seems very silly to do this in Python when you could just write `mv *.pdf convert.pdf` in an sh-compatible shell (the default on most non-Windows systems) or `rename *.pdf convert.pdf` in cmd (the default on Windows). But if you really want to, you can do it in two ways.

```
import glob, os
for name in glob.iglob('*.pdf'):
    os.rename(name, 'convert.pdf')

import os
for name in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.splitext(name)[1] == '.pdf':
        os.rename(name, 'convert.pdf')
```